# How does the bios know what type of BPB is present?

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader

If I want my bootloader to boot from a usb stick, I have to include a BPB. The usb stick is running in floppy emulation mode. As seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_parameter_block), there are many different BPB versions. How does the bios know what type of BPB is present? GRUB 0.97 seem to be using yet another [BPB](http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/GRUBbpb.htm) format ?

I can pad my bootloader from offset 0xb a little, and then it will also work. 
Is there a standard/common size to use? I am not using any filesystem on my USB, just raw.

I guess I need the BPB because the bios tries to update some on the values, which overwrite some of the code. Since every BPB seems a little different, how can the bios know where to update what value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all BIOS implementations care if you have a BPB.  The general format for the BPB with the beginning of an MBR boot sector is below:

```
bits 16
org 0                   ; BIOS will load the MBR to this location.

    bootStart:
            jmp     _start
            nop
            osType      db  'MSDOS6.0'
            bpb
            bps         dw  512
            spc         db  8
            rs          dw  1
            fats        db  2
            re          dw  512
            ss          dw  0
            media       db  0xf8
            spfat       dw  0xc900
            spt         dw  0x3f00
            heads       dw  0x1000
            hidden      dw  0x3f00, 0
            ls          dw  0x5142,0x0600
            pdn         db  0x80
            cheads          db  0
            sig         db  0x29
            serialno    dw  0xce13, 0x4630
            label       db  'NO NAME'
            fattype     db  "FAT32"

    _start:
                                ; set up the registers
            mov     ax, 0x07c0
            mov     ds, ax
            mov     fs, ax
            mov     gs, ax
            mov     ax, 0x0700
            mov     es, ax
```

The fields are always in the same place..  The way that the system, if it cares about the BPB, verifies it is simply by parsing it.

Comment: [GRUB](https://github.com/jezze/grub-legacy/blob/master/stage1/stage1.S) line 65 to 85 uses a different order doesn't it? The values in it is also set to zero, isn't it then ok to just pad the bpb space with zeros?

Comment: Well, theoretically it would be, but I've had systems that refuse to boot an otherwise valid MBR unless some of this is reasonable, especially up through the heads.

Comment: @user237948 : You can pad the space with zeroes (you need that JMP to start though). In the GRUB code they use the BPB space for their own variables. They don't care what the BIOS might put there, they end up overwriting the data anyway (If using a floppy they retrieve the drive geometry from the BIOS itself).One reason to put sane values in there that represent the drive is in the event that you are using disk images you can actually get mount software to read the header and decide the disk image configuration from the BPB entries.

Comment: I just noticed a bug that really doesn't make this a proper BPB. Before `osType` there are 3 bytes you need to fill in. the short JMP takes 2 bytes so you should place a _NOP_ (or some other byte) after the `jmp _start`. You can see the problem if you do `file boot.bin` (the name of your bin file generated from this code). `file` will not recognize it as a boot header. Inserting the _NOP_ should make it a compliant _BPB_ and `file` should be able to detect it as such.