# Why can I not show characters when I boot from a USB

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

I'm trying to display a message (letter 'A') on the screen just after run the computer. Without hard disk, just a file that I create in assembly and I put in a USB-drive.

The code is:

```
mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, 0x41
int 0x10

jmp $

times 510-($-$$) db 0x00
dw 0xaa55
```

And then I put in the linux terminal:

```
nasm boot.asm -o boot.bin
```

It works with qemu, but not when I put in a USB and then I put this USB in a computer. Any idea?

Comment: [You might need a BPB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42144059/547981)

Comment: Maybe it's the reason why it doesn't work. But I don't understand what this code is doing. Probably, changing parameters of the BIOS? I'd like to have some documentation or info about this. If you can recommend me something, i'd be thankful to you...

Comment: This code invokes a service from PC firmware, `AH=0Eh` specifies that you want the function [TELETYPE OUTPUT](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm).   
Here is a better description of structures [BPB and DPT](https://euroassembler.eu/maclib/bioss.htm#BPB_FAT16).

Comment: Ok. Thank you!!